# Unable to get property 'pingInterval' of undefiened null reference

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, base64, encode

I submit a form to take objects from database.

I need to add varbinary(MAX) type (image) column inside json string, and send it via WebMethod to Ajax to display in the page, with the rest of the properties of the object. So in the class its string type instead of byte[] type.

In the encoding part I receive Javascript runtime Error:

> Unable to get property 'pingInterval' of undefiened null reference.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
   Arrival:
   <input type="text" id="txtArrival" />
        departure:
   <input type="text" id="txtDeparture" />
   Nob:
     <input type="text" id="txtNob" />
     <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Get Rooms" />
 </form>
```

## Class:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string RoomType { get; set; }
public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
public string RoomTitle { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
public string ServiceName { get; set; }
public string Photo { get; set; }
```

## Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var arrival = $("#txtArrival").val();
            var departure = $("#txtDeparture").val();
            var nob = $("#txtNob").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetRooms",
                data: "{'arrival':'" + arrival + "','departure':'" + departure + "','nob':'" + nob + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

## WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GetRooms(string arrival, string departure, string nob)
        {
            string val = "";
            DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(arrival);
            DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(departure);
           int noib=Convert.ToInt32(nob);
            var jSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Room> lst = new List<Room>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=ResDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("roomsAvailable", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arr", d1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", d2);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nob", noib);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ;
                    while (sr.Read())
                    {
                        Room r = new Room();
                        r.ID = Convert.ToInt32(sr["ID"]);
                        //objects..
                        if (sr["Photo"] != System.DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            byte[] p = (byte[])sr["Photo"];
                            r.Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p);// error here
                        }

                        lst.Add(r);
                        val = jSerialize.Serialize(lst);
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            return val;
        }
```

Error is in this statement in WebMethod:

```
 r.Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(p);
```

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/874794/unable-to-get-property-pinginterval-of-undefiened-null-reference

Answer (score 0):

After changing JQuery hosted file to newer version,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Error disappeared!